# How to force release CGContext and Font cache?

Tags: ios, core-text

There is a novel reader module in our app, when user uses this module to read some ebooks, the memory has greatly increased. When user exits the reader component, the memory is not decrease , but there is no memory leaks....

We use Instruments (Allocations) to analysis the memory, there is a lot of render (we use Core Text to render text to image, then display the text to user via ImageView) and font caches!! We try to force a memory warning, the memory is still not released!!

Is there any way to force release system text render and font cache?

Thanks a lot!